# Display DISQUS on homepage

Tags: comments, templates, homepage, disqus

I have installed disqus and I want it to show up on my homepage. It replaced the old wordpress comments system on pages and posts but I also want it to appear on index.php

my index.php file now - > https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyFBf.png

I added <`?php comments_template(); ?>`  but nothing happend. What should I do ? I want to put it at the bottom of my website

Thanks

Comment: Can you please link to the plugin Docs which includes the template tag.

Comment: Are you sure that's the template tag for Disqus?

Answer (score 1):

Hook it in from your child themes functions file or add the template tag to a front-page.php file

**Untested**

```
add_action('loop_end','disqus_front_page_after_loop');

function disqus_front_page_after_loop() {

if (is_front_page() && function_exists( 'comments_template' ) ) {

comments_template();

    }
}
```

Change the loop_end [hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to another WordPress or theme specific hook.

If using the template tag, you might want to try adding it before the footer rather than before the end of the loop if it works outside the loop.